# Date created in formula

Tags: date, whencreated

I am trying to have a calculated column which to show the year and the month of item creation and a letter in front.
I tried the formula :

```
="R"&RIGHT(YEAR(Created);2)&MONTH(Created)
```

but this shows R181, and I want R1801.

I tried also :

```
="R"&RIGHT(YEAR(Created);2)&IF(MONTH(Created)<10,"0"&MONTH(Created))
```

but I have an error message.

It seems also that function `=TEXT(Created,"mm")` is not working anymore.

Any solution?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job for the leading zeros:

```
="R"&RIGHT(YEAR(Created);2)&TEXT(MONTH(Created);"00")
```

Edit:

I think the problem with your intent was using "," instead of ";".

Comment: perfect, thank you very much for quick support. Works as i wanted.